# Get quotient and remainder from array in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm

Hi All I have one array with 1 to 1000 numbers

```
int[] Numbers={1,2,3,4,5,6............1000};    
float CalculatedBy=3.5;
```

I want to get quotient and remaining values  into the array by CalculatedBy value(the above float variable)

**My code:**

*First I split this array to char array*

```
    Char[] splitNumbers=Numbers.split(",");

    foreach( int charNumber in splitNumbers)
    {

    if(charNumber % CalculatedBy==0 )
    {
    //i know i am totally going to wrong way So what will i do ? 
    }    
}
```

**My main conditions are :**

*I want to write quotient and remaining values in console window with this format*

> Value 1: 
>   Result is : Q is 1 and R is 1
>
> value 2 : 
>   Result is : Q is 1 and R is 1

And **i don't want display the remaining value is 0 .**

Comment: Whoever upvoted the question - please edit it so it somewhat resembles C# or JavaScript code... I.e. what `Numbers.split` supposed to means or `foreach(...as ...)`

Comment: Now am changed some code !!!! Sorry for my issue !!!

Comment: No It's one of the technical interview question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below:

```
int[] Numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
float CalculatedBy = 3.5F;

foreach (int number in Numbers)
{
    if (number % CalculatedBy != 0)
    {
        int quotient = (int) Math.Floor(number / CalculatedBy);
        float remainder = number - quotient * CalculatedBy;
        Console.WriteLine("Value {0}: Result is : Q is {1} and R is {2}", number, quotient, remainder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to char array,

```
int[] Numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
float CalculatedBy = 3.5F;

foreach (int n in Numbers)
{
    if (n % CalculatedBy != 0)
    {
        int q = (int) Math.Floor(n/ CalculatedBy);
        float r = n- q * CalculatedBy;
        Console.WriteLine("Value {0}: Result is : Q is {1} and R is {2}",n,q,r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using whole numbers instead of floats, an alternative would be to use the [Math.DivRem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yda5c8dx.aspx) method.

```
int[] Numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int CalculatedBy = 3;

foreach (int number in Numbers)
{
    if (number % CalculatedBy != 0)
    {
        int remainder;
        int quotient = Math.DivRem(number, CalculatedBy, out remainder);
        Console.WriteLine("Value {0}: Result is : Q is {1} and R is {2}", number, quotient, remainder);
    }
}
```